# mySQL trigger not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, triggers

**Answered**
I just needed to add new.ingredient = old.ingredient in my WHERE clause.

Essentially I have three tables (this is for school so I am constrained in the design here). The first table, ingredients, contains the cocktail name, the ingredient and the serving size (so if there are multiple ingredients there are multiple entries per cocktail). The second table, cost, contains the cost per ingredient. The third table, cost_to_make, has the price per cocktail, calculated from the previous two tables.
I need to design a trigger so that each time the serving size in ingredients is updated, the price of the cocktail in cost_to_make is recalculated using the new serving size from ingredients, and the cost per ingredient in costs. My current code is below and it's not behaving how I expect.

Essentially atm if the price of an ingredient changes, the trigger is updating the prices of all the cocktails, not just the cocktail that contains the ingredient. If anyone could point out where I've gone wrong here, I'd be very grateful.

```html
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_cost
AFTER UPDATE 
ON ingredients FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE cost_to_make, ( 
    SELECT sum(price * serving_size) as new_price,
            cocktail
    FROM costs
    INNER JOIN ingredients
    ON ingredients.ingredient=costs.ingredient
    GROUP BY cocktail) as prices 
    
SET cost_to_make.cost = prices.new_price
    WHERE cost_to_make.cocktail = prices.cocktail;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Use the value of altered ingredient identifier in WHERE.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I've been going round in circles all day.